# How to structure / design events and tasks in a quest system to make code manageable?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, event-handling, observer-pattern

I'm creating a Javascript game that provides quests for the user to play through. Each quest has a number of tasks which are completed when certain requirements are met. Below is the design I originally intended to go with.

[image]

As you can see, each `Task` and `GameEvent` (simplified to `Event`) has a type and some data (encapsulated in a dict). When an event is sent to `QuestManager`, it is passed along to the active `Quest` objects who in turn pass it on to each `Task` assuming their types are the same. Each `requirement` in the task is then tested against the correlating `data` in the event. The reason why I don't do 1:1 checks is because an event may have additional data.

e.g `data{item: someItem, locationFound: someLocation} != requirement{item: someItem}`

This works great in terms of minimising the number of classes that need to be created. Events and tasks are generic so they can be easily created and tested against without creating a ton of sub-classes.

But this design creates a problem. Because of its generality, it is never certain what requirements should be given to a task without first finding an event of the same type and checking the data being sent to it. As the project expands, this becomes a nightmare to manage.

Instead, I could create sub-classes for both `Event` and `Task` that would cover the various types, like this:

```
Event -> ItemPickupEvent, MoveEvent, etc.
Task -> ItemPickupTask, ItemPickedUpAtLocationTask, MoveTask, etc.
```

But the data is similar between them and seems highly unnecessary.

My final thought was to create data objects to encapsulate the data being passed by certain event types, as follows:

ItemPickupData, MoveData, TalkData etc.

Events and tasks could just be given the appropriate data object. This provides better structure to the data being used. If a piece of data should not be made into a requirement, it could simply be defaulted to null.

In terms of maintainability and structural design, is this an adequate solution or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Because of its generality, it is never certain what requirements should be given to a task without first finding an event of the same type and checking the data being sent to it.

As I understand, the problem is that almost the same data is duplicated in the event object and task object.

For example, you have `Event { 'type': 'ItemPickup', data: { 'name': 'MagicSword', 'kind': 'weapon' } }`.

And then you want to add a task to pickup the magic sword and you create the `Task { 'type': 'ItemPickup', data: { 'name': 'MagicSword' } }`.
So this is the problem and here you need to lookup how exactly you have configured the event and put the same data into the task object.

I think the solution to move this data into separate objects should work well.
Another thing which doesn't look right is that you have `type` field and it hints that you need to have subclasses.
And this also would be solved if you create the data objects like `ItemPickupData`, `MoveData`, etc.

An alternative can be to have the `Event` itself to be this data object and have something like this (pseudocode):

```
class Event // base class for events with common data and methods

// the subclasses can be almost empty
class ItemPickupEvent extends Event  
class MoveEvent extends Event

class Task
    _requirements = [
        new ItemPickupEvent('MagicSword'),
        // and maybe it is even better to wrap events into "Requirment" objects, 
        // which can, for example, be marked as completed
        new Requirement(new MoveEvent('OldForest')),
        ...
    ]
```

And then you could then manage requirements this way:

```
class Task
    isComplete(event)
        complete = false
        // go over requirements to see if this task is complete
        for requirement in this._requirments:
           complete = complete && requirement->isComplete(event)
        return complete

class Requirement
    isComplete(event)
        # check event class and properties to understand if the requirement is satisfied
        if class(event) == class(this._event):
            if event.isNameMatches(this._event):
               this->_complete = true
        return this->_complete
```

It can also be done without the class name check. 
The idea is to have base `Requirement` class has special methods for each event class and rejects them by default.
Subclasses then can handle specific event types:

```
class Requirement
    isComplete(event)
        // redirect the type detection to event object
        return event->isComplete(this)

    isCompleteItemPickup(event)
        return false

    isCompleteMove(event)
        return false

class ItemPickupRequirement
    isCompleteItemPickup(event)
        // here we know that event is ItemPickupEvent
        if event.isNameMatches(this._event):
               this->_complete = true
        return this->_complete

class MoveRequirement
    isCompleteItemPickup(event)
        // here we know that event is MoveEvent
        if event.isNameMatches(this._event):
               this->_complete = true
        return this->_complete
```

The `isComplete` method of the `Requirment` class is used from the `Task` class and it re-directs type detection to the event object.
The event object then passes itself back to the appropriate method of the requirement:

```
class Event
    isComplete(requirement) // should be implemented in subclasses

class ItemPickupEvent
    isComplete(requirement)
        // here we call the specific requirement method
        // now we know the exact event object type (it is ItemPickupEvent)
        return requirement->isCompleteItemPickup(this)

class MoveEvent
    isComplete(requirement)
        return requirement->isCompleteMove(this)
```

The structure may look a bit complicated, but depending on the specifics, you may need the `Requirement` class and it's sub-classes anyway (for example, there can be generic `ItemPickupRequirement` and some specific `PowerItemPickupRequirement`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems like in the end it was inevitable to revert back to subclasses for both events and tasks. As you say, there will be times when a requirement will have to be more specific (i.e perhaps needing to process an extra property). For the moment, all data needed by a task will be captured in an EventData object so if I simply check against non-null properties I can test with some flexibility. If for some reason this produces problems in the future, I will have to look at an approach more in line with your own thoughts.

Comment: @sookie one more note, I think that avoiding creating a lot of classes is a mistake, it may look like it saves you from complexity and from a lot of typing, but actually it doesn't. You still have to write code for all your entities, just instead of small subclasses you use small data structures, but it easier to manage small subclasses then untyped and method-less data structures.